# Why is my function returning an array with undefined as items?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function that accepts an array and then returns a copy of that array with randomized items, however it keeps returning an array with at least one index as undefined -why?

```js
function randomize(array) {
  let newArr = array.slice(); //creates copy of array

  let arLength = newArr.length; //gets array length
  let newCollection = []; //creates a new array to restore items into

  let numList = []; //creates a new array to document the iterated random items

  function genRandNum() { //generates a random number and if the number already exists inside of numList it runs again

    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * arLength);
    if (numList.includes(randNum)) {
      genRandNum();
    }
    return randNum;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arLength; i++) {
    let randomNum = genRandNum(); //gets random number

    numList.push(numList); //adds random number to random number list

    let item = newArr.splice(randomNum, 1)[0]; //gets index value of the array past in

    newCollection.push(item); //adds randomly pick item to the new array
  }
  return newCollection; //returns the new randomized array
}
console.log(randomize(["a","b","c"]));
```

Comment: I created a snippet, and changed newVideoCollection to newCollection

Comment: You need to check `let item = newArr.splice(randomNum, 1)[0];` I think it does not do what you expect it to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several JavaScript functions for randomising an array, you can easily find them. My intention here is not *improving* your code or proposing those alternative functions... instead of that, I'll just point out the issues in your code.

You have two problems:

1. you want to push `randomNum` into `numList`:

   ```
   numList.push(randomNum);
   ```
2. `splice` changes the length of the array. Because of that, the length of `newArr` decreases every time you do `let item = newArr.splice(randomNum, 1)[0];`, and it's not equal to `arrLength` anymore.

Therefore, you could use `while` instead, passing the length of the array to `genRandNum`. The logic behind this is that, every time you do a `splice`, the length of the array decreases.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
function randomize(array) {
  let newArr = array.slice(); //creates copy of array

  let newCollection = []; //creates a new array to restore items into

  let numList = []; //creates a new array to document the iterated random items

  function genRandNum(arLength) { //generates a random number and if the number already exists inside of numList it runs again

    let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * arLength);
    if (numList.includes(randNum)) {
      genRandNum();
    }
    return randNum;
  }

  while (newArr.length) {
    let randomNum = genRandNum(newArr.length); //gets random number

    numList.push(randomNum); //adds random number to random number list

    let item = newArr.splice(randomNum, 1)[0]; //gets index value of the array past in

    newCollection.push(item); //adds randomly pick item to the new array
  }
  return newCollection; //returns the new randomized array
}
console.log(randomize(["a","b","c"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is that genRandnum does not always return an unused index; it does check for this, and recursively computes a new number, but then returns the original anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
}

var myArray = ["a","b","c"];
shuffle(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

```
function random(arr) {  
  var new_arr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    new_arr.splice(getRandom(0, arr.length), 0, arr[i]);
  }

  function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }

  return new_arr;
}

var new_array = random(['a', 'b', 'c']);

console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the array of newVideoCollection on line 26.

and it is not correct to push array to the same array again on line 22, if understand correctly you need to randomize the array but in very not clean way.